# How to output top 10 strings from MySQL database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

The database looks at New York's subway system data. I would like to output the top 10 amounts of Exits and their corresponding Stations names on one line. I am very new to the Java and MySQL environments. This is the code that I am currently working with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/project3", "root", "root");

    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Stations, Date, Entries, Exits FROM `table 3` ORDER BY Exits DESC LIMIT 10");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();


    while(result.next()){
        System.out.println(result.getString("Exits"));
        System.out.print(result.getString("Stations"));
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Console reads:

```
9
LEXINGTON AV/539
LEXINGTON AV/539
LEXINGTON AV/539
125 ST9
125 ST9
LEXINGTON AV/539
CANAL ST9
103 ST9
103 ST9
LEXINGTON AV/53
```

(obviously not the output that I am looking for)

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: what do you need? the result that you are getting is not the one you need, then what you need?

Comment: I changed PHPMyAdmin to MySQL because the database software you're using is MySQL. PHPMyAdmin is just a more user-friendly program for managing your MySQL database.

Comment: I need ("Exit Amount" + "Station Name") all on one line. 10 lines total (top 10)

Comment: As a general tip - don't select columns you're not going to use

Comment: It's not obvious to me. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()` function to concat `Exits` and `Stations` and get the required format from sql only

```
...
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT CONCAT(Exits, ' ', Stations) AS exitsandstations FROM `table 3` ORDER BY Exits DESC LIMIT 10");
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();


while(result.next()){
    System.out.println(result.getString("exitsandstations"));
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue! Greatly appreciate your time Raman Sahasi.